# Proxy Sensor not detected in android phone

Tags: android, proximitysensor

```
 mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
     am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     if(mSensorManager.getSensorList(SensorManager.SENSOR_PROXIMITY).size()>0)
     {
         hasproximity=true;
         psensor=mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(SensorManager.SENSOR_PROXIMITY);
         mSensorManager.registerListener(this,psensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
     }
     else
     {
         hasproximity=false;
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Proximity Sensor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         stopSelf();
     }
```

This is the code i am using for accessing the proximity sensor but i am getting a toast notification that no proximity sensor is available but my phone sony xperia j has proximity sensor

can any one help me

is there any uses-permission required to access proximity sensor ?
I tried to access accelerometer sensor with out any uses-premission tag it worked fine for me